# Do we know if Ginyu is in his real body?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

When Ginyu first shows up he appears to be of a similar race to that of Freeza and King Cold but later we learn that he can swap bodies.

Do we know if, when Ginyu first arrived on Namek, was he in his original body? or has he already stolen that body from someone else?

Comment: Ginyu's special skill is to steal the powerful body of a warrior so that he can have the power. I'm assuming he rose in rank by repeatedly doing so and getting more powerful and seeing how his subordinates accepted the fact, it was not his first time and they were all perfectly aware what to do

Comment: In the anime definitely no proof. In the manga, trivia and interviews with Toriyama however.... that's like pandora's box.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. He could have switched bodies several times before we saw him. [Ginyu's Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Ginyu) notes

> Only a few people have seen Ginyu's true form, and Salza is among them

Which implies the form we saw was not his original.